# Do memory mapped objects get freed up automatically after a thread terminates?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, memory, posix

I have a few quick questions. If I create a new child thread in C, after the thread has finished its processing and it terminates, do:

- Memory mapped objects get "automatically" freed up? (I know C does not have a garbage collector, but at this point the child has terminated)

Guess I posted too fast. Found the answer to the second question (for future ref): http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-memory-leaks/index.html?ca=drs-

- Can the child return a value to the parent thread? (Is this possible using some common routine? I know that the memory space of the child and parent are the same?)

Also I would like to mention that the OS is POSIX compliant.

Thanks,
Neco

Comment: Note: you should differ between "child/parent" and threads.
If child return and OS detect problem with unfreed memory, it might kill parent.
One way or another, you should always free the dynamically allocated memory in C. Simple exit() is not enough, you may want to consider jums (long jumps or goto[is not evil(tm)]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already found out, the answer to your first question is "no". That goes for objects allocated on the heap too.

There is no parent&child relationship between threads in a process, so "parent thread" is meaningless. But, yes, threads can return a value when they exit. The prototype for a thread's toplevel function is:

```
void *function(void *);
```

Observe that the return type is `void *`. Threads can return a pointer (to anything you like). This return value will be retrieved by any other thread that waits for the returning thread to complete using `pthread_join()`.

Answer (score 0):

Resources like memory, file handles, mutexs, etc. are not released when a thread exits.  However, all process related resources are released when a process exits which includes all those types of objects.